# Mongo: Upsert to copy all static fields to new document atomically

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, aggregation, upsert, bucket

I'm using the Bucket Pattern to limit documents' array size to `maxBucketSize` elements. Once a document's array `elements` is full (`bucketSize` = maxBucketSize), the next update will create a new document with a new array to hold more elements using `upsert`.

How would you copy the static fields (see below `recordType` and `recordDesc`) from the last full bucket with a single call?

Sample document:

```js
// records collection
{
  recordId: 12345, // non-unique index
  recordType: "someType",
  recordDesc: "Some record description.",
  elements: [ { a: 1, b: 2 }, { a: 3, b: 4 } ]
  bucketsize: 2,
}
```

Bucket implementation (copies only queried fields):

```js
const maxBucketSize = 2;

db.collection('records').updateOne(
  {
    recordId: 12345,
    bucketSize: { $lt: maxBucketSize } // false
  },
  {
    $push: { elements: { a: 5, b: 6 } },
    $inc: { bucketSize: 1 },
    $setOnInsert: {
        // Should be executed because bucketSize condition is false
        // but fields `recordType` and `recordDesc` inaccessible as
        // no documents matched and were not included in the query
    }
  },
  { upsert: true }
)
```

### Possible solution

To make this work, I can always make two calls, `findOne()` to get static values and then `updateOne()` where I set fields with setOnInsert, but it's inefficient

How can I modify this as one call with an `aggregate`? Examining one (last added) document matching `recordId` (index), evaluate if array is full, and add new document.

### Attempt:

```js
// Evaluate last document added
db.collection('records').findOneAndUpdate(
  { recordId: 12345 },
  {
    $push: { elements: {
      $cond: {
        if: { $lt: [ '$bucketSize', maxBucketSize ] },
        then: { a: 5, b: 6 }, else: null
      }
    }},
    $inc: { bucketSize: {
      $cond: {
        if: { $lt: [ '$bucketSize', maxBucketSize ] },
        then: 1, else: 0
      }
    }},
    $setOnInsert: {
      recordType: '$recordType',
      recordDesc: '$recordDesc'
    }
  },
  {
    sort: { $natural: -1 }, // last document
    upsert: true, // Bucket overflow
  }
)
```

This comes back with:

MongoError: Cannot increment with non-numeric argument: { bucketSize: { $cond: { if: { $lt: [ "$bucketSize", 2 ] }, then: 1, else: 0 } }}